# How to iterate json object using jQuery - GeoNames.Org api

Tags: jquery, json

i am getting `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data`on console. unable to iterate .

```
 var url ="http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeSearchJSON?postalcode=110085&maxRows=100&username=demo";
            $.post(url, function(results) {
            var myJSONObject = JSON.parse(results);
            for(var i = 0; i < myJSONObject.postalCodes.length; i++)
            {
                var name = postalCode[i]["name"];
                alert(name);
            }

        });
```

Comment: Sounds like your `results` are invalid JSON.

Comment: The error you are getting is related to `JSON.parse`, not the loop. The first step to solve this would be to look at the value you are passing to `JSON.parse`. Is it a string? Is it valid JSON? etc. Also: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var url ="http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeSearchJSON?postalcode=110084&maxRows=100&username=dhirajshivaji";
        $.post(url, function(results) {
        for(var i = 0; i < results.postalCodes.length; i++)
            {
                var name = postalCodes[i]["adminName3"];//change
                alert(name);
            }



        });
```

Comment: why are you giiving anser to your own question?   Please mark above answer of mine as answer

Comment: @amit giving answer to own op is totally valid

Comment: @amitwadhwani bcz its gave me option for adding own ans :D

Answer (score 2):

result is already a JSON object so need not to parse and use it as is.

```
 $.post(url, function(results) {
            //var myJSONObject = JSON.parse(results); change
            for(var i = 0; i < results.postalCodes.length; i++)
            {
                var name = postalCodes[i]["adminName3"];//change
                alert(name);
            }
```

Also there isn't any key called "name" in response so i have changed the code there, and changed postalCode"s" as an array name.

Comment: `ReferenceError: postalCodes is not defined`

Comment: http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeSearchJSON?postalcode=110085&maxRows=100&username=demo  in browser is returning postalCodes,   If you are using any different url then you have to update the code. But this uurl should work with postalCodes

Comment: so shall i assume that its working? as per your second comment?

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it has resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use jquery each method

```
var url = "http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeSearchJSON?postalcode=110085&maxRows=100&username=demo";
$.post(url, function(results) {
  $.each(results.postalCodes, function(key, val){
    console.log(val.adminName3)
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remember, that you shouldn't go to stackoverflow with every error, especially when you got exception and it's message is clear. At first you should learn how to read this kind of messages. There are mainly set to direct you to solution (but you have to think for a while). Anyway, exception message indicates, that there are some errors related to JSON.parse method, which is used to parse recieved string to eg. javascript object. You are using some api, and as we all know virtually every api which is exposed to the world, return json object. Let's think for a while. You try to parse JSON to JSON? Yes and this is causing exception.